# MAMP OS X Conflict with Built in Apache with Virtualhostx

Tags: apache, macos, mamp

I am a newbie and I set up Mamp and virtualhostx on my IMAC and it works fine except when I restart the server in virtualhostx it tells me multiple servers are running and it could cause conflicts. I can go into settings and turn off Apache but it starts again when I restart with virtualhostx.

I used the setup suggested in http://seansperte.com/entry/Setting_Up_a_Killer_Local_Web_Development_Environment_on_a_Mac_with_MAMP_an/

and set my Apache and Mysql ports to to 80 and 3306 respectively

How can I keep the built in Apache turned off?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Answer from this source: http://tosbourn.com/turn-off-the-built-in-apache-on-osx/
with explanation. Worked for me. The above answer also doesn't work for me because sharing was completely disabled for me (nothing ticked in the first place).

Comment: I have the file org.apache.httpd.plist in the indicated folder, but when i launch the command, Terminal reply me that "Could not find specified service". So, I have the file but it seems it is not a service... Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi Aerendir, I'm sorry but I would not know. I'm not great at these things myself. You may find something here in turning off autostarting applications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065288/how-to-remove-autostart-of-apache-on-macosx

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it in System Preferences > Sharing. Remove the check next to "Web Sharing".