# How to remove autostart of apache on macosx

Tags: macos, apache

I'm on a macosx lion. A service is up and running on localhost:8080.

This service is an apache + php packaged by entreprisedb.

How could I remove the autostart ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**1)** The autostart is usually not in the User-Autostart-Items, but you should check them anyway:

Open the **System-Preferences** > **Users** > *Select your user* > **Start-Objects**

Check if there is something started you want to deactive and do so if.

**2)** Normally the start of apache is handled by the launchd-service: You can either change this manually, or with the help of a old little tool named "[Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/)". To do it manually, you need to find the launchd-folders:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents
~/Library/LaunchDaemons

/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons

/System/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

There you'll find .plist-files, that define when and what to start. To remove a object from auto-start use launchctl on the terminal to remove it from the actual launchd and then simply delete the file.

```
user$ launchctl unload *filename.plist*
```

Make sure you do not delete the wrong files! This may lead to a fatal situation on your machine. Btw: The .plist-Files can be read with [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) or the [PropertyList Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#Property_List_Editor) from the [Apple Developer-Tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/).

Comment: The launchctl command has not worked (throw an error Could not blabla), but I have edited the plist file corresponding to apache and mark desactivated option to true. Thank you +Erik

Comment: +1 and `ps -el | grep -E "httpd|apache"` is a way to check what may be running. That along with `/path/to/httpd -V` showed me I had a process running with the wrong config file.

Comment: use `launchctl list` command to get a list of all the available launchd plist files.  You can then use `launchctl unload name.of.the.plist`

Comment: The `launchctl list` command did not reveal the item I found within `/Library/LaunchDaemons` which appears to be the issue. That's a symlink to macports apache `org.macports.apache2.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/org.macports.apache2.plist` Because it's a symlink I can't unload it or the original! This problem started for me upon upgrade to OSX Lion.

Comment: Also note: `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

Comment: Don't forget sudo... For instance `launchctl list | grep apache` may return empty, but `sudo launchctl list | grep apache` could list:
61 - org.apache.httpd

Comment: Option 1 in OSX 10.9 Mavericks looks like 
`System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items`

Comment: @Motin - Will `launchctl` will list active agents and daemons from `/Library` and `~/Library` and will `sudo launchctl` also include those from `/System/Library`?

Comment: @Tobias, don't know. Sounds reasonable. Anyone?

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I had used homebrew to install and setup launchctl for mysqld. I searched for a lot of time before finding this answer.
I searched in /System/Library folder and /Library folder but completely forgot about home library ~/Library.

I had homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist defined in /Users/vp/Library/LaunchAgents

This command worked for me
launchctl unload homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

Answer (score 27):

On Mountain Lion (OSX 10.8.5) I was able to disable the Apache server that ships with OSX using the following command:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

This particular command probably won't work if a different version of Apache was installed via MacPorts or HomeBrew.

The use of `sudo` is important, as Apache needs root privileges to run on a low-numbered, protected port number (port 80).

Comment: I like it! I tried it on Mavericks - the command works fine, but Apache is still started when the machine is rebooted. Just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: I get this "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service"

Comment: @MartinGolpashin I get that error when I have unloaded the service. But when I try to load the service and unload again it's gone. I think that error is because the service has been unloaded already. That's my theory.

Comment: 10.9.4 `launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd`

Comment: 10.12.6 - I had already installed updated apache via homebrew.  launchctl unload would not work until I first tried to load again (which also indicated failure). After that, unload worked properly. Thanks to JohnnyQ.

Answer (score 7):

Erik's answer it's almost a complete list of places where you can found startup items.
There are two others places where I've found several apps starting up even if you press SHIFT during login.

> /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist
>
> /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist

You can read them using:

> defaults read /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist
>
> sudo defaults read /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist

Comment: on Lion, it was both of these overrides.plist where I finally found where Sophos antivirus was being disabled.

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to do `sudo apachectl stop`.

Then to start it do `sudo apachectl start`. This will also make the web server start on system start too.

This works as I am telling you because these commands call `launchctl`` under the hood. You can verify this by running

```
$ cat `which apachectl`
```