# MAMP - Mac OS X

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost, mamp

I have been using MAMP for sometime now on port 8888 so I visit website in the browser like so: `http://localhost:8888/website`

However I have just installed a Wordpress Multisite and therefore want to switch to port 80 to allow me to visit the websites as normal and have sub directories e.g. `http://website.co.uk`, `http://subdomain.website.co.uk`

I have setup the vhosts file within MAMP and changed the port to 80 in the MAMP preferences but ever since doing this MAMP will not start Apache. MySQL starts up fine but Apache fails to start.

I have tried to start apache manually by running the following command in terminal:

`sudo ./startApache.sh`

but everytime I do this I get the following errors:

```
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

If I switch back to port 8888 MAMP works again. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this fixed?

```
sudo lsof | grep LISTEN

launchd      1           root   11u     IPv6  0x8754c7c05566afd       0t0      TCP *:afpovertcp (LISTEN)
launchd      1           root   12u     IPv4  0x8754c7c0556bae5       0t0      TCP *:afpovertcp (LISTEN)
launchd      1           root   30u     IPv6  0x8754c7c0556671d       0t0      TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
launchd      1           root   31u     IPv4  0x8754c7c0556b3ad       0t0      TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
httpd       21           root    4u     IPv6  0x8754c7c0556633d       0t0      TCP *:http (LISTEN)
kdc         43           root    6u     IPv6  0x8754c7c05565f5d       0t0      TCP *:kerberos (LISTEN)
kdc         43           root    8u     IPv4  0x8754c7c0556a53d       0t0      TCP *:kerberos (LISTEN)
httpd      191           _www    4u     IPv6  0x8754c7c0556633d       0t0      TCP *:http (LISTEN)
Dropbox    293            Ell   19u     IPv4  0x8754c7c0a8db6cd       0t0      TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox    293            Ell   25u     IPv4  0x8754c7c0a8da125       0t0      TCP localhost:26164 (LISTEN)
mysqld     454            Ell   10u     IPv4  0x8754c7c0ba8085d       0t0      TCP *:ddi-tcp-2 (LISTEN)
```

Update:

```
ps 21
PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
21   ??  Ss     0:00.39 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can check what processes that are listening on what ports with `lsof`:

```
sudo lsof | grep LISTEN
```

Look for processes listening on `*:http` etc.

**Update:**

You see that one process is already using `*:http` which is a process named `httpd` with pid 21. `httpd` is most likely a Apache process. So I would guess that your system already have an Apache installation somewhere (that might auto start) or that the MAMP Apache is already running for some reason.

Try to run `ps 21` to get more information about the process. On my system where I have MAMP installed an running I see this: (65696 is the pid of `httpd` on my system).

```
mattias@waderbook:~$ ps 65696
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
65696   ??  Ss     0:00.57 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -k start
```

If you see `/usr/sbin/httpd` it is likely the Apache bundled with OS X that is running. Try to disable it by going to "Sharing" in Preferences and disable "Web sharing".

Comment: please see my added section of my original question with the output of that command. Can you see anything obvious there?

Comment: I have updated again to show the output of the ps 21. I also tried to disable the Web Sharing option but it isn't shown in the list: http://d.pr/i/KV7H

Comment: Hmm thats a bit weird hmm, have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065288/how-to-remove-autostart-of-apache-on-macosx on how you might be able to stop it. The launchd config for apache is called `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` default. Does it exist for you? and if you look inside the file is Disabled set to true or false?

Comment: You should be able to stop it by running `sudo apachectl stop` but i would guess it will start again on reboot.

Comment: Disabled is set to true : <key>Disabled</key> <true/>. Running the apache stop then starting it in MAMP fixes it, is there a way to permanently disable the default apache?

Comment: Hmm not really sure what is starting apache at startup if it is disabled for launchd. Can you look at the startup items for your user in preferences? Maybe this question can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065288/how-to-remove-autostart-of-apache-on-macosx?lq=1

Comment: Did you figure out what is starting apache?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was nothing to be found when using grep on `lsof`.

I've been looking for a few hours to find what was creating the Listen directives to overlap but without result.

So I've used a quickfix, and that was to change my Listen port in httpd.conf to 8000

`Listen 8000`

change that, and restart your apache2. Should do the trick...